# What is a good (commercial) high capacity SFTP Server for Windows?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ftp, sftp

We are currently using Titan FTP Server, but we have found that it has a memory leak.  It also seems to fail two to three times a week during high load periods causing problems for our clients. When the Titan FTP Server fails, rebooting the actual (hardware) server seems to be the only way to fix the problem.  When we have upgraded to their latest server code the problem becomes much worse. I have also tried working with their customer support and they have not been able to resolve the issue.

Hence, we are looking to replace the Titan FTP Server with another commercial grade FTP Server.  We do all file transfers using SFTP and SFTP capability is a requirement.  We transfer files to and from a large number of clients and the file sizes range from fairly small to 20MB.  At peak times we may have 40 or more clients connected and either uploading or downloading files to the server.

Our environment is Windows Server 2008 Standard running on a 64 bit machine with 32GB of memory.

Comment: To bee clear you want SFTP not FTPS?

Answer (score 2):

Another software on that Wiki list is [GoAnywhere Services](http://www.goanywheremft.com/products/services). I've installed it at a number of client locations and they have loved the Active Directory integration, rock-solid performance on a small foot-print, security controls and that you can do everything via a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Not a Windows guy so I can't make any direct recommendations, however http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SFTP_server_software may be a good starting place.

Glancing at the list I can tell you that [Serv-U](http://www.serv-u.com/) has been around pretty much forever - I remember using it under Windows 95 way back in the stone age - so it's probably fairly well debugged at this point and may make a good choice.

Comment: Serv-U is probably the best of the lot for windows. Been using it forever.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look into [Syncplify.me Server!](http://www.syncplify.me/products/server/) which scales up pretty well, even in multi-node HA (high-availability) deployments, and supports local as well as Windows and Active Directory users and groups.

For 40 (or even 100) concurrently connected clients the machine you have (64 bit Windows 2008 with 32 GB RAM) will work just fine, but it can easily scale up to several hundreds of concurrent clients with a proper HA deployment.